# how do I write the file_browser_callback function in tinyMCE 4

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to be able to add an image into the text area. Currently, I can add the image if I give the URL of the image. 
What I want is to be able to browse images on my PC and add it to the textarea. I dont know how to write the file_browser_callback function. I have read the official documentation on it, but that doesnt solve my problem. 
here is my code:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: '#mytextarea',
theme: 'modern',
skin: 'lightgray' ,
width: 600,
height: 300,
plugins : [
  'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
  'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
  'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor code'
],

toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | code',

statusbar:false,
code_dialog_height: 300,
code_dialog_width: 350,

images_upload_url: 'uploadImage.php',
images_upload_base_path: '/some/basepath',
images_upload_credentials: true,
automatic_uploads: false,
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = 'my browser value';

},
file_browser_callback_types: 'file image media'

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you really read the documentation? Because it describes very well how to write this function and explaining every row of code you could need for it.
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser
What eactly did you not understand?

Besides that, you need a file browser. Browser_callback_function only starts an external tool and wants to receive tha path/url to the file as return value.
You might look at some third party file browsers for tinymce, like one of these:
http://www.roxyfileman.com/
http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/

Comment: the described functions from 3.x also works for 4.x.  
You can refer to the tinymce plugin of the mentioned filemanagers. (e.g. http://www.roxyfileman.com/TinyMCE-file-browser , i use this one in my projects with tinymce )